# Synchronize asynchronous back end

Tags: java, synchronization, jms, nonblocking, completable-future

I need to create a REST endpoint which will "synchronize" requests and responses to/from backend service working by JMS. In other words, my endpoint should send a message to the JMS input queue, wait for a response in the JMS output queue. If there was no response in a timeout period then error returned to the consumer. And for the consumer this endpoint should look like a normal synchronous request/response.

Currently I've implemented it using java.util.concurrent.Exchanger. 
My code (simplified):

REST endpoint:

```
@RestController
public class Endpoint {

   private ConcurrentMap<String, Exchanger> exchangers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

   @GetMapping("/data/{requestId}")
   public ResponseEntity<String> getData(@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.PATH, required = true) String requestId) {
      Exchanger<String> syncExchanger = createAndPutIfNotExists(requestId);
      sendToJMS(requestId);
      int timeout = 30;
      // wait for JMS response and return it
      return waitForResponse(syncExchanger, requestId, timeout);
   }

   private synchronized Exchanger<String> createAndPutIfNotExists(String requestId) {
        if (exchangers.get(requestId) != null) {
            throw new BadHeaderException("Duplicate requestId");
        }
        Exchanger<String> exchanger = new Exchanger<>();
        exchangers.put(requestId, exchanger);
        return exchanger;
   }

   private String waitForResponse(Exchanger<String> exchanger, String requestId, int timeout) {
        try {
            return exchanger.exchange(null, timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return "interrupted";
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            throw new TimeoutException("timeout on waiting JMS response.", e);
        } finally {
            exchangers.remove(requestId);
        }
   }

   @JmsListener(destination = "${jms.outputTopic}")
   public void onMessage(Message m) throws JMSException {
      String requestId = m.getStringProperty("RequestId");
      String payload = m.getBody();
      Exchanger<String> exchanger = exchangers.get(requestId );

      if (exchanger != null) {
            try {
                exchanger.exchange(payload);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } finally {
                exchangers.remove(requestId );
            }
      }
   }
}
```

The solution works. But it **blocks** requests threads while waiting for a response.
Then webserver thread pool runs out of limit at high load.

*Is there a way to do this in a non blocking manner?*

Something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/data/{requestId}")
   public CompletableFuture<String> getData() {
      return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        sendToJMS(requestId);

        // How to wait for JMS response with some timeout ?

      });
   }

@JmsListener(destination = "${jms.outputTopic}")
   public void onMessage(Message m) throws JMSException {
      String requestId = m.getStringProperty("RequestId");
      String payload = m.getBody();

      // How to "complete" CompletableFuture ?

   }
```

Comment: I think it's better to use synchronous invoke rather than message queue in this scenario since you need to wait for the response. On the other hand, it will always block if the response takes a long time unless you use asynchronous invoke or message queue(without waiting for the response).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring accepts `CompletableFuture` as a return type in controllers, so you could create one in `createAndPutIfNotExists()` and complete it in `onMessage()`.

Replace your `exchangers` map with a `futures` map:

```
private ConcurrentMap<String, CompletableFuture<String>> futures = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

then adapt the sending part:

```
@GetMapping("/data/{requestId}")
public CompletableFuture<String> getData(@PathParam("requestId") String requestId) {
    CompletableFuture<String> future = createAndPutIfNotExists(requestId);
    sendToJMS(requestId);
    int timeout = 30;
    CompletableFuture<String> result = future.orTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    result.thenRun(() -> futures.remove(requestId, future));
    return result;
}

private synchronized CompletableFuture<String> createAndPutIfNotExists(String requestId) {
    if (futures.get(requestId) != null) {
        throw new BadHeaderException("Duplicate requestId");
    }
    CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    futures.put(requestId, future);
    return future;
}
```

Note that the timeout handling is performed using Java 9's `orTimeout()` method. If you are on Java 8, you will need [custom timeout hanlding](http://iteratrlearning.com/java9/2016/09/13/java9-timeouts-completablefutures.html).

You may also want to do some `thenApplyAsync(s -> s, executor)` trick to move the response submission out of the JMS / timeout handling threads.

Finally, just `complete()` the future when receiving the response:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${jms.outputTopic}")
public void onMessage(Message m) throws JMSException {
    String requestId = m.getStringProperty("RequestId");
    String payload = m.getBody();
    CompletableFuture<String> future = futures.get(requestId);

    if (future != null) {
        try {
            future.complete(payload);
        } finally {
            futures.remove(requestId, future);
        }
    }
}
```